# Application.OnTime throwing "Object Required" error even though I clearly put the object

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is throwing an error when I attempt to schedule it to run itself later. I have pounded my face on the desk to the point of exhaustion, but no help.

It errors on the "Application.OnTime" line and says: Run-time error '424': Object required.

```
Public Sub WaitForItGas()

rtime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

If Range("GasDoneCheck").Value <> 1 Then
    DoEvents
    Applicaion.OnTime EarliestTime:=rtime, _
                      Procedure:="WaitForItGas", _
                      Schedule:=True
    DoEvents
Else
    
    MsgBox "done"

End If

End Sub
```

I have tried declaring the name of the procedure to schedule (in this case the name of the procedure itself), a string variable, as a public constant. I have tried setting it to schedule running another sub, which in turn runs this sub. I have tried various versions of formatting on my code. It's pretty simple code, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: In what kind of a module is `WaitForItGas` located? Standard, Object (Sheet, ThisWorkbook), or Class module? You have a typo: it should be `Application`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application` is spelled wrong.

```
Public Sub WaitForItGas()

    rtime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    If Range("GasDoneCheck").Value <> 1 Then
        DoEvents
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rtime, _
            Procedure:="WaitForItGas", _
            Schedule:=True
        DoEvents
    Else
    
        MsgBox "done"

    End If

End Sub
```

### Addemdum

As FunThomas commented, use `Option Explicit` will make it easier to catch these types of errors.

[Using Option Explicit in VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-uhsCL2UHE)

Comment: I am simultaneously horrified and elated. I hate you and thank you so much.

Comment: @Dadgumit I hate you too because obviously you can type. I can't type so I use autocomplete.  Thanks for accepting my answer!!

Comment: @TinMan: You should at least mention that those errors can easily be avoided using `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @FunThomas I didn't think about it.  Thanks!

Comment: I will never forget this. Just searching for `x1Up` and `x1Down` (instead of xlUp and xlDown) gives > 250 hits on SO - every single question is obsolete.